# Архив *.tar.gz linux, нужно разархивировать рекурсивно

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

Архив  - `files.tar.gz`.Содержимое папки созданой командой(`tar -
xvzf files.tar.gz`):

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 root     root       4096 лип  3 03:17 assets
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     210245 лип 16 15:43 church-pastor.sql.gz
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     root        249 лип  3 03:17 config.core.php.gz
drwxrwxrwx  3 root     root       4096 лип 17 01:42 connectors
drwxrwxrwx 12 root     root       4096 лип 17 01:41 core
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       4412 лип 17 01:24 error.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       7088 лип 15 20:36 font-awesome.min.css.gz
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root       4096 лип 17 01:41 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        187 лип  5 20:11 .gitignore.gz
```

Как разархивировать все файлы в подкаталогах?

Comment: Судя по наличию папки `.git`, у вас в архиве проект с git-репозиторием. Причем заархивированы и файлы/папки в рабочей области, и хранилище (собственно, папка .git). В хранилище уже есть содержимое всех файлов рабочей области, причем оно там довольно эффективно заархивировано.

Comment: Правильно — не архивировать проект под git, а перенести папку `.git` – можно просто скопировать, а можно через git – клонировать через фс, либо запушить в репозиторий на сервере и клонировать оттуда.

Comment: я так(как вы описали) всегда делаю, но доступ  был  только через ftp. Я неправильно заархивировал на сервере, после чего на локалке пришлось пересобирать архив, для того чтобы отправить его через ftp и там через билинг хостинга распаковать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае похоже, что так:

```
tar -xzf files.tar.gz; find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip '{}' \;
```